# AS3 load mp3 from some point of time

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3

I have to make some kind of mp3 player in as3 (flash). My problem is load mp3 from some starting point (on time line). For example, if I click on 1:15 min and only 30 sec of video is loading, I have to load video from 1:15 sec. In Sound class is   load(stream, context) function, but I need one more argument - startTime.

I appreciate any idea.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After loading sound you call the `Sound.play(startTime:Number = 0, loops:int = 0, sndTransform:flash.media:SoundTransform = null):SoundChannel`[method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play%28%29), the first parameter is what you need.

UPD: 
Flash doesn't support loading mp3 with offset so you have to load all file. The only way to do this is to use media server like FMS pack your mp3 to mp4 container without video and use NetStream class, but this is very complex task for just playing mp3 :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, this is not what I need. I don't need play from some point when sound is loaded. I need load sound not from beginning, but from some point, for example from 1:15. In other words, I don't need load all video, but one part, from some point till end.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Flash doesn't support loading mp3 with offset so you have to load all file. The only way to do this is to use media server like FMS pack your mp3 to mp4 container without video and use NetStream class, but this is very complex for just playing mp3 :)